# Как подключить ДБ в двух файлах?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

в первом файле,я подключаю ДБ и настраиваю её:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///massages.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class DataBase(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_user = db.Column(db.Integer)
    type= db.Column(db.String(10))
    type_int = db.Column(db.Integer)
    massege = db.Column(db.Text)
    id_user_bans = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<DataBase %r>' % self.id
```

как мне эту же базу подключить в другом файле?

Answer (score 0):

Я использую данный код и запускаю global_init перед app.run() а далее создаю сессию через create_session()

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as dec


def global_init(db_file):
    global __factory

    if __factory:
        return

    if not db_file or not db_file.strip():
        raise Exception("Необходимо указать файл базы данных.")

    conn_str = f'sqlite:///{db_file.strip()}?check_same_thread=False'
    print(f"Подключение к базе данных по адресу {conn_str}")

    engine = sa.create_engine(conn_str, echo=False)
    __factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    from . import __all_models

    SqlAlchemyBase.metadata.create_all(engine)


def create_session() -> Session:
    global __factory
    return __factory()


SqlAlchemyBase = dec.declarative_base()

__factory = None
```

в __all_models импортируются все модели. Модель выглядит например так:

```
import datetime
from werkzeug.security import *
import sqlalchemy
from .db_session import SqlAlchemyBase
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin


class User(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                           primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, unique=True)
    nick = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    karma = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, default=0)
    hashed_password = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    modified_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime,
                                      default=datetime.datetime.now)
    confirm = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, default=False)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.hashed_password, password)
```